# How to display the attribute of an object as a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two classes `List` and `Task`:

```
class List
  attr_reader :all_tasks

  def initialize
    @all_tasks = []
  end

  def add (task)
    @all_tasks << task
  end

  def show
    all_tasks
  end
end

class Task
  attr_reader :description

  def initialize (description)
    @description = description
  end
end
```

And the following code:

```
breakfast = Task.new("Make Breakfast")

my_list = List.new
my_list.add(breakfast)
my_list.add(Task.new("Wash the dishes!"))
my_list.add("Send Birthday Gift to Mom")

puts "Your task list:"
puts my_list.show
```

Output:

```
Your task list:
#<Task:0x00007fd9e4849ed0>
#<Task:0x00007fd9e4849e30>
Send Birthday Gift to Mom
```

I want to be able to show the tasks of the to-do list as a string and in the same time have the `Task` instances as objects inside the array. How do I do that?

Comment: Note that although `attr_reader :all_tasks` looks like read-only, it allows the caller to modify `all_tasks`, e.g. `my_list.all_tasks << 'another task'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `add` with `Task` instances:

```
my_list.add(Task.new("Wash the dishes!"))
```

and with `String` instances:

```
my_list.add("Send Birthday Gift to Mom")
```

Having a mixture of both, `Task` and `String` instance in one array makes it harder to work with. Unless you really want or need this, I would change `add`, so it converts string arguments to `Task` instances:

```
class List
  # ...

  def add(task)
    task = Task.new(task) unless task.is_a? Task
    @all_tasks << task
  end
end
```

[`is_a?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F) checks whether `task` is (already) a `Task`. If not, it is passed as an argument to `Task.new` which returns such instance. This ensures, that `@all_tasks` only contains `Task` instances.

Your current implementation of `List#show` simply returns `all_tasks`, i.e. an array. Although [`puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/IO.html#method-i-puts) is able to print arrays ...

> If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line.

... I would change `show` to return a formatted string:

```
class List
  # ...

  def show
    all_tasks.map { |task| "[ ] #{task.description}" }.join("\n")
  end
end
```

[`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-map) returns a new array with a string for each task instance. Each string contains the corresponding task's `description`, prefixed by `[ ]` which should resemble a little check box. [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-join) then concatenates these string elements using `"\n"` (newline) as a separator.

Output:

```
Your task list:
[ ] Make Breakfast
[ ] Wash the dishes!
[ ] Send Birthday Gift to Mom
```

Comment: Thank You again. This is even better. I feel like i made a big jump in understanding Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the code in your question, it would suffice to simply redefine method `to_s` of Task.

```
class Task
    attr_reader :description
    def initialize (description)
      @description = description
    end

    def to_s
      "Task: #{description}"
    end
end
```

#### Output

```
Your task list:
Task: Make Breakfast
Task: Wash the dishes!
Send Birthday Gift to Mom
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that this works because `puts` prints each element on a new line if called with an array. To have more control over the output, `List#show` should return a string.

Comment: Thank you that really helped. Since I am only started to learn ruby(my second week), i would like to now, why the moment I write the def to_s, ruby doesn't display the string representing the output anymore?

Comment: @Stefan Can you please also explain what List#show is/means and how to implement it? It might be stupid question but I won't learn anything if i don't ask :-) Thank You again for your help

Comment: @SebastianPeter `List#show` refers to the `show` instance method within your `List` class. It currently returns an array, whereas it probably should return a string. I've posted an answer showing a slightly different approach.